# Is my e-commerce app's code compliant with MVC?

Tags: node.js, mvc, typescript, express.js, e-commerce

Hi I have spent few days reading about various architectures and decided to use MVC (Model-View-Controller).
But I had hard time applying all the theory to my node.js code. I've wrote some minimal backend code as close to MVC architecture as I could. (*note: it hasn't "View" part at all, but I plan to use "ejs" framework for that*)

Could you please review my code and tell me does it have correct MVC architecture or any at all?
I would love to hear any other remarks about the code as well!

*Note: I didn't design the data structures yet (for example "shoppingItem" is not complete it is just a draft), I just want to be sure that I'm on the right way before I continue.*

I've uploaded this project to [github](https://github.com/FaigBagirov/ecommerce_for_review/tree/review) for your convenience.

My folder structure is like this:

```
├── main.ts
├── .env
├── _config
|   |── db.ts
|   └── index.ts
├── _controllers
│   |── addToCart.ts
│   |── cancelCheckout.ts
│   |── checkout.ts
│   └── _workers
|       |──addToCartWorker.ts
|       |──dbMigrationWorker.ts
|       └──index.ts
├── _entities
│   ├── products.ts
│   ├── shoppingItem.ts
│   └── user.ts
├── _models
│   ├── shoppingItemsActions.ts
│   └── shoppingOrders.ts
└── _routes
    └── shoppingRoutes.ts
```

**main.ts** file

```
// const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const {port} = require("./config"); 
//This should be inside the separate route files, but I still have problems with importing the route files
const addToCartController= require('./controllers/addToCart')

const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const db_test = require("./db_test");

//I have problems with importing the routes file
//Just ignoring it for now
//all routing code relies here in the routes module
// const routes = require("./routes/shoppingRoutes");
// routes(app);

//Didn't need it yet
// var cors = require('cors'); 
// app.use(cors());

//TODO: maybe have to move it above the "routes(app);"" line
//configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware to parse the body of post requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post("/addtocart", (req: any, res: any)=>{
    console.log(`my get request`, req.body)
    addToCartController.addToCart(req, res);
});
router.post("/checkout", (req: any, res: any)=>{
    console.log(`my get request`, req.body)
    addToCartController.checkout(req, res);
});

app.use(router);

//Don't need it right now during the tests
// app.get("/", (req: any, res: any)=>{
//     console.log(`get request`, req)
// })

//Just to test connection with the database
db_test.select('*', 'userCart');


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
```

**.env**

```
PORT=8000
API_URL=http://localhost/api
API_KEY=asdfsafsfsfdasdsassd
POSTGRE_URL=
```

**/config/index.ts**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
module.exports = {
    endpoint: process.env.API_URL,
    masterkey: process.env.API_KEY,
    port: process.env.PORT
}
```

**/controllers/addToCart.ts**

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
import {ShoppingItem, ShoppingItemType} from '../entities/shopingItem';
const addToCartWorker = require('./workers/addToCartWorker');

module.exports = { 
    addToCart (req: Request<{}, {}, ShoppingItemType>, res: Response) {
 
        let shoppingItem = req.body;
        console.log('request.body FROM ADDTOCART: ', shoppingItem);

        // //check before insertion
        addToCartWorker.before(shoppingItem);

        // // insert new row
        addToCartWorker.add(shoppingItem);

        // // confirm insertion
        addToCartWorker.after(shoppingItem);

        //respond to frontend
        res.status(200).send(shoppingItem);
        return req;
    }
}
```

**/controllers/workers/addToCartWorker.ts**

```
export {};
import {ShoppingItemType} from '../../entities/shopingItem';

// TODO: replace "object" with actural return value
// TODO: implement sequelize as an ORM
type addToCartWorker = {
    before: (arg0: ShoppingItemType) => object;
    add:    (arg0: ShoppingItemType) => object;
    after: (arg0: ShoppingItemType) => object;
}

const addToCartWorker:addToCartWorker = {
  before: (arg0: ShoppingItemType) => {
    // return db.any('SELECT * FROM articles');
    console.log("running code before adding to cart");
    return arg0;
  },

  add: (arg0: ShoppingItemType) => {
    // return db.any('SELECT * FROM articles');
    console.log("adding new item to userCart table");
    return arg0;
  },

  after: (arg0: ShoppingItemType) => {
    // return db.none(`INSERT into articles(title, content)` + `VALUES($1, $2)`, [title, content]);
    console.log("running code after adding to cart");
    
    return arg0;
  },

};

module.exports = addToCartWorker;
```

**/entities/shopingItem.ts**

```
interface ShoppingItemType  {
    productId: number;
    productQty: number;
    userData: {
        userID: string,
        userToken: string,
    };
}
class ShoppingItem implements ShoppingItemType{
    productId: number;
    productQty: number;
    userData!: { //TODO: not sure if I can to use "!"" here 
        userID: string;
        userToken: string;
    };

    constructor({productId, productQty, userData}: ShoppingItemType){
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productQty = productQty;
        this.userData.userID = userData.userID;
        this.userData.userToken = userData.userToken;
    }
}

export {ShoppingItemType, ShoppingItem};
```

**/routes/shoppingRoute.ts**

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
export {};
const addToCartController= require('../controllers/addToCart')

//I have problems with the routes file
//Just ignoring it for now
module.exports = (app: any) => {
    router.post("/addtocart", (req: any, res: any)=>{
        console.log(`my get request`, req.body)
        addToCartController.addToCart(req, res);
    });
    router.post("/addtocart", (req: any, res: any)=>{
        console.log(`my get request`, req.body)
        addToCartController.checkout(req, res);
    });

}
```

Comment: Is this code working yet, if it isn't it is not ready for a code review. Get the code to where you can test it and know that it is working as intended. We would love to review it then. We can only review what is in the question, we can use the repository for supporting information only.

Comment: This might be more on-topic over at [SoftwareEngineering](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/), but before posting there please [**follow their tour**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Yes, this code works, but it responds back same object. just clone the repo and install the dependencies. 
I have turned off the database part since I cant share my azure db credentials.

Comment: @BCdotWEB
No, they said that it it's topic isn't related to them